# can guid be duplicated in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, guid

I have created one field named guid varchar(36) in my one table in mysql. In this field, I am inserting value with UUID(). I want this field unique. So, my question is mysql's UUID() can return duplicate value ever?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers that are not connected to each other.

But it is returning **128** chars

Answer (score 0):

From the docs A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Since the query is compiled before being executed, you are calling UUID() twice at the same moment in time. Therefore, you cannot expect it to return two unique values in the same query since the same timestamp would be used for both values. This sounds like intended behavior to me.

Check it here ( I will also copy answer from here )

[MySql UUID duplication BUG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750536/mysql-uuid-duplication-bug)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the algorithm is anywhere near halfway decent, which it looks to be, the short answer is *no*.

The number is generated from a monotonously increasing timestamp counter (in layman's terms it means the counter always goes forward and never duplicates itself) and to safeguard against two values being generated at the exact same instant, depending on the architecture, either a spacial component (MAC address) or a random component.

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid):

> A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different values, even if these calls are performed on two separate computers that are not connected to each other.

---

The long answer is, *yes it is technically possible to generate the same UUID twice, but the probability of being struck by a meteorite is often greater*. If the number were completely randomly generated (note on MySQL only one part of the number may be random, the other parts are derived from a timestamp counter), Wikipedia [puts it nicely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid):

> The probability of one duplicate would be about 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.

Which certainly qualifies for "good enough". If you're *really* worried, just slap a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column for extra comfort.