# Insert different UUID on each row of a large table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ~80k rows with imported data.  Table structure is as follows:

```
order_line_items  
  - id  
  - order_id  
  - product_id  
  - quantity  
  - price  
  - uuid
```

On import, the order_id, product_id, quantity, and price were imported, but the uuid field was left null.

Is there a way, using mysql's UUID() function, to add a uuid to each row of the table in bulk?  I could use a script to cycle through each row and update it but if there is a MySQL solution, that would be fastest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each call to `uuid()` returns a different, unique value.

So a simple

```
UPDATE order_line_items SET uuid = uuid();
```

should assign each `uuid` field a unique value.

---

**Edit March 2022**

Note that using this method only a few characters change in the uuids, which make them look identical at a glance, but actually they're all different.

---

*Edit June 2020*

With @RickJames (see comments) we are trying to comprehend how some people can get the same UUID after running the `Update` command above (they should be all different).

1. MySQL/MariaDB. The question is tagged [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ; be sure you are running MySQL or MariaDB, as another DBMS might not render that MySQL behavior for the UUID() on multiple rows
2. Perform the `Update` as shown here, `UUID()` is a MySQL function (thus the `()`)
3. Check the field that receives the Update, it must be large enough to hold `36` chars

See also this [related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269189/mysql-uuid-behavior) on DBA SE.

Comment: well, at least on AWS Aurora


aurora_version
1.17.3
innodb_version
1.2.10
protocol_version
10
slave_type_conversions
version
5.6.10
version_comment
MySQL Community Server (GPL)
version_compile_machine
x86_64
version_compile_os
Linux

Comment: @AlexanderPopov What is the type of your field? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056220/store-uuid-v4-in-mysql

Comment: This didn't work for each different row. I updated all my rows with an unique uuid with from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53888040/7662267

Comment: @klendi - What version of MySQL/MariaDB/Aurora?  Show us the whole SQL statement.  Was it inside a Stored Routine?

Comment: I got different values; what are we doing differently?  See my Answer in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269189/mysql-uuid-behavior

Comment: @RickJames That's the question... In my case nothing simpler than the Update above. Maybe other engines (myisam...?) work differently. NB, I'm glad someone gets different uuids as well!

Comment: @e2-e4 - MyISAM worked the same (diff uuids for single update) in 9 versions.  Mysterious.

Comment: @AlexanderPopov - Please provide a stand-alone test case.

Comment: I also received the same UUID value for all rows. `UPDATE MyTable
SET uuid = UUID();`. This is on `MySQL/InnoDB version8.0.19

Comment: I have a reproduction of the problem with `UPDATE` causing all UUIDs to be the same, using docker-compose, here: https://gist.github.com/guss77/6747e48dd401d1ad36e5b4092ccfcfdd (there's also a video). I noticed that if I perform the update after the database is finished initializing (instead of as part of the setup), then UUIDs are different - I think it is a performance issue as I observe the problem with a high performance RDS database but not in a test on a local slow machine.

Comment: Be aware, using this method only a few characters change in the uuids, which make them *look* identical at a glance, but actually they're all different. I spent a good 15mins thinking this was failing when actually it was working. I wonder if this is catching other people out too.

Comment: Thank you @iHiD this was also the case for me!

Answer (score -1):

According to my own tests, it only changes the first 8 characters. This means about 4 billion different values (16 ^ 8). If I have a big table let's say 10 million entries, this means that I have a collision with the probability of ~ 1 : 400. Honestly. This uuid generation is not worth much. In the case you really have a big table with millions of data. So exactly then when this function would be handy, you should generate the uuids outside of mysql.