# UUID not valid at this position (Mysql workbench)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I was trying to create a table and in this I was using id attribute as UUID but it is showing error that it is not valid at this position it is expecting something else

```
CREATE TABLE  account (
a_id                    UUID                PRIMARY KEY,
a_hash                  VARCHAR(66)         NOT NULL,
a_email                 VARCHAR(500)        NOT NULL,
a_password              VARCHAR(60)         NOT NULL,
a_verification_key      UUID                NOT NULL,
a_disabled              BOOLEAN             DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
a_verified              BOOLEAN             DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
a_role                  VARCHAR(20)         NOT NULL,
a_created_at            TIMESTAMP           DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
```

);

Here a_id field is UUID type and a_verification_key is also UUID
and it is giving me error in mysql workbench

Comment: which version of mysql db you are using  ???

Comment: UUID is a function not a datatype - try searching for mysql uuid.

Comment: you change the datatype to `VARCHAR()` from UUID as `UUID` can be used as datatype

Comment: @scaisEdge I am using 8.0.13(Version)

Comment: @Patel Romil you are saying that I need to remove this UUID and change to varchar

Comment: @RajatAgrawal Please take a look at the answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store UUID v4 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056220/store-uuid-v4-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge,@P.salmon,@Alan Hay for the help everyone I resolved my error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UUID, specify `columnDefinition` to `VARCHAR(255)` or `CHAR(16)` or `BINARY(16)` using `@Column`, with this you can use the functionality of *UUID*. You may change *strategy* and *generator* as per your requirement

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(name = "a_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
private UUID a_id;
```

[Discussion](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,49626,49626) [Function UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)