# How to generate UUID in python withing given range

Tags: python, mysql, uuid

I need to generate UUID for MYSQL **int** and **BigInt** which needs to be in a **given range** and I need **10 digits** integer UUID for which I have written a code

```
def getUniqueID():
    unique_id = uuid4().int & (0 << 32) - 1
    return unique_id
```

for example, SQL int should not exceed the limit of 2147483647.(unique_id < 2147483647).

```
def getUniqueID(min,max):

    unique_id = uuid4().int & (0 << 32) - 1
    return unique_id
```

SQL int Limitation found here,

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: That's not a UUID then. It's just a random number in a certain range.

Comment: `UUID` Universally Unique Identifier. If you specify new rules it is no longer a UUID as deceze said. Please ask a different question.

Comment: Yes, but I am searching for an option to generate UUID somehow. In my schema data type in INT/BIGINT so MySql won't accept if its exceeds its limit.

Comment: You should probably just use a auto incrementing number for your SQL table.

Comment: UUID is often stored as a string not an int.... Or a UUID type.

Comment: See [Storing UUID Values in MySQL Tables](https://mysqlserverteam.com/storing-uuid-values-in-mysql-tables/). In otherwords UUIDs should be stored in `VARCHAR(36)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store UUID v4 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056220/store-uuid-v4-in-mysql)

Comment: *"In otherwords UUIDs should be stored in VARCHAR(36)"* Not really `binary(16)` is much better ,,, @SyntacticalRemorse  ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Very True (though it does lose human readability). As long as no one needs to read it in the database I would definitely go with that option. This is covered in the duplicate question above.

Comment: how often do you need to read it anyhow, just make a simple VIEW which can make it readable on the fly when you need it..  @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, That's 100% true it should be in varchar. Here DB design not with me, that's why am searching for a solution.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestions my dear developers, I will look forward to schema changes itself.

Comment: *" That's 100% true it should be in varchar."* No `VARCHAR(36)` is actually the worst datatype to choose for storing UUID .. a `CHAR(36)` would then still make a (bit) more sense as it is using less bits on disk as the lenght of a UUID never changes.. VARCHAR uses extra bytes (one or two) on disk to define how much is used from that lenght making selections slower.,, Anyhow that `binary(16)` is much better as  [charset/collate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) rules do not slow it down when selecting on `binary(16)` or take up more space then needed..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes make sense, I go through some of the articles as well. Gonna use fixed-length UUID's so CHAR(36) is a wiser choice.

Comment: *"Gonna use fixed-length UUID's so CHAR(36) is a wiser choice"* if you going to use `CHAR(36)` atleast define it as  `CHAR(36)  CHARSET ascii` to get the best performing and least disk space needing charset/collate  for what you need..

Answer (score 0):

First you can install **shortuuid** with:

```
python -m pip install shortuuid
```

then you can use it like this:

```
import shortuuid
print(shortuuid.ShortUUID().random(length=10))
```

the project is in github: https://github.com/skorokithakis/shortuuid

Comment: Not a bad solution but it switches to using full ASCII instead of Hex for UUIDs.