# mysql: how put two columns unique in two tables at once

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, cl

**hi**
in MySQL i want to put two (unique) fields in two different table, in my example i have three table, login table, prof and user. I want the field (id_user) and the field (id_prof) not to be repeated to insert them also after (unique) in the login table in the field (num)
e.g: id_user 1, 3, 6 ...
id_prof: 2, 4, 5, 7 ...
num: 1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...

[image: prof table]

[image: login table]

[image: utilisateur]

Comment: you could try a before nsert trigger and get the max number of bith and add one, but ths system can fail. so why not use uuidv4s , they are unique

Comment: can you explaine more please ! how can I use this uuidv4s ?

Comment: insetad of the number you have a varchar(36) field and add the builtin function uuid() to the insert.or beeter the [uuidv4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965743/how-to-generate-a-uuidv4-in-mysql) so now every id is unique and you can send them via trigger to the login page

Comment: sorry I dont understand, can you answer how can I use this trigger please

Comment: or, there is an idea , I put id_user auto increment in pairs and id_prof auto increment in odd , the question is , can I do this in MySQL

Comment: hm Build a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER SELECT THE max id from prof  and from user  and increase the highest number of both and use that as id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the version with two Triggers.

But it can happen, that concurrent entries will have not unique numbers, also on heavy duty servers this also fails.

So you have to take login id unique and catch when the insert fails and then try to get  anew id

> ```
> CREATE TABLE prof(id BIGINT, name varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user(id BIGINT, name varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE login(id BIGINT, name varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_prof_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON prof FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE prof_ BIGINT;
>     DECLARE user_ BIGINT;
>     DECLARE res_ BIGINT;
>     SELECT MAX(id) into prof_ FROm prof;
>     SELECT MAX(id) into user_ FROm user;
>     
>     IF user_ IS NULL AND @prof IS NULL THEN
>         SET res_ := 1;
>     ELSE
>         IF user_ > prof_  THEN
>             SET res_ := user_ + 1;
>         ELSE
>             SET res_ := prof_ + 1;
>         END IF;
>     END if;
>     SET NEW.id = res_;
>     
>     INSERT INTO login VALUES (res_,NEW.name);
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER before_user_insert
> BEFORE INSERT
> ON user FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE prof_ BIGINT;
>     DECLARE user_ BIGINT;
>     DECLARE res_ BIGINT;
>     SELECT MAX(id) into prof_ FROm prof;
>     SELECT MAX(id) into user_ FROm user;
>     
>     IF user_ IS NULL AND prof_ IS NULL THEN
>         SET res_ := 1;
>     ELSE
>         IF user_ > prof_  THEN
>             SET res_ := user_ + 1;
>         ELSE
>             SET res_ := prof_ + 1;
>         END IF;
>     END if;
>     SET NEW.id = res_;
>     
>     INSERT INTO login VALUES (res_,NEW.name);
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO prof VALUES (0,'profa');)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUES (0,'usera');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO prof VALUES (0,'profb');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO prof VALUES (0,'profc');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user VALUES (0,'userb');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO prof VALUES (0,'profd');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM prof;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name 
> -: | :----
>  1 | profa
>  3 | profb
>  4 | profc
>  6 | profd
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name 
> -: | :----
>  2 | usera
>  5 | userb
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM login;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name 
> -: | :----
>  1 | profa
>  2 | usera
>  3 | profb
>  4 | profc
>  5 | userb
>  6 | profd
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e2c34313fc8479503c32b6ba476f6f13)*

Much easier it would be

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (uuidv4(),'usera');
INSERT INTO prof VALUES (uuidv4(),'profa');
```

This would guarantee that the ids are unique for every table.

Comment: thank you so much, so I must delet my tables and re create it or can I continue with my old tables ( prof, user, login )?

Comment: for the trigger solution, you need to remove the auto_incrmeet , if you have it in the for the second you need to change  the int to varchar but you can use them overaall with out a problem.