# MySQL generate UUID() for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add UUIDs to some tables in some of my MySQL databases (MySQL 5.7.9). First of all, I start by adding a column to receive the UUIDs:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD COLUMN `Uuid` BINARY(16) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Then, for all entries that are already in the table, I generate UUIDs (since every entry in the DB will have received a NULL value in it's UUID field.

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET Uuid= unhex(replace(uuid(),'-','')) WHERE Uuid IS NULL;
```

Now, the thing is that I get some very weird behaviour by doing this; on some of my databases, every UUID generated is unique (as expected). However, on other databases, all generated UUIDs are identical (not similar, identical).

I suspect that this is due to the MySQL query optimiser, since behaviour is not consistent between different database instances (all on MySQL 5.7.9). However, I have no clue how to solve this issue.

So, MySQL gurus, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . This is an old bug report and the code to fix it should have been committed a decade ago.  Do you know if the fix was never incorporated into the code base?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750536/mysql-uuid-duplication-bug

Comment: @GordonLinoff His query is calling UUID repeatedly with the same timestamp, at least this is my guess.  Do you know of a workaround?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but the solution was a [later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51393124/394360) to the linked question.  I had a default character set of utf8mb4, and the theory is that it implicitly converts uuid()'s utf8 result to a constant string, before the sql executes.  Converting the other parameters to utf8 avoids that:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET Uuid= unhex(replace(uuid(), _utf8'-', _utf8'')) WHERE Uuid IS NULL;
```

The later answer links to the [relevant (not a) bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12774).  [This SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53614419/mysql-5-7-function-uuid-default-collation-illegal-mix-of-collations) looks related.

Answer (score 4):

Best solution is:

`UPDATE mytable SET Uuid= MID(UUID(),1,36) WHERE Uuid IS NULL;`

Comment: This is brilliant. The only thing that worked

Comment: Agree this is simple and works.  An explanation would be useful.  Why does selecting the first 36 characters randomize the result?

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750536/mysql-uuid-duplication-bug) from @TimBiegelsen works.

I declared a function to generate UUID according to v4 standard.

```
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_v4()
    RETURNS BINARY(16)
BEGIN
    -- Generate 8 2-byte strings that we will combine into a UUIDv4
    SET @h1 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h2 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h3 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h6 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h7 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');
    SET @h8 = LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0xffff)), 4, '0');

    -- 4th section will start with a 4 indicating the version
    SET @h4 = CONCAT('4', LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0x0fff)), 3, '0'));

    -- 5th section first half-byte can only be 8, 9 A or B
    SET @h5 = CONCAT(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 4 + 8)),
                LPAD(HEX(FLOOR(RAND() * 0x0fff)), 3, '0'));

    -- Build the complete UUID
    RETURN UNHEX(LOWER(CONCAT(@h1, @h2, @h3, @h4, @h5, @h6, @h7, @h8)));
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```